# Group and count patient records based on date of last visit with a physician

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here's my data:

```
+----------+---------------+------------+---------------------+
|  doctor  | received_date | patient_id | accession_daily_key |
+----------+---------------+------------+---------------------+
|  A       |  1/1/2011     |  ABC123    |                   1 |
|  A       |  1/20/2011    |  AAA123    |                   2 |
|  A       |  1/21/2011    |  AAA123    |                   3 |
|          |               |            |                   4 |
|  A       |  2/1/2011     |  ABC123    |                   5 |
|  A       |  2/9/2011     |  BBBYYY    |                   6 |
|          |               |            |                   7 |
|  B       |  1/2/2011     |  ABC123    |                   8 |
|  B       |  1/20/2011    |  AXA435    |                   9 |
|  B       |  1/19/2011    |  AAA123    |                  10 |
|          |               |            |                  11 |
|  B       |  2/1/2011     |  ABC123    |                  12 |
|  B       |  2/10/2011    |  BBBYYY    |                  13 |
+----------+---------------+------------+---------------------+
```

Here's the result I want:

```
+--------+-------+--------------------+
| doctor | month | count new patients |
+--------+-------+--------------------+
| A      |     1 |                  1 |
| A      |     2 |                  1 |
| B      |     1 |                  2 |
| B      |     2 |                  0 |
+--------+-------+--------------------+
```

I would like to count the new patients for a doctor every month.

The business rules I've been given are:

> 1. a patient can be associated with only one doctor
> 2. the doctor to which the patient is associated is the LAST doctor that saw him

Here's what I have so far:

```
select patient_id,max(month(RECEIVED_DATE)) AS Mnth, max(year(RECEIVED_DATE)) AS Yr, ACCESSION_DAILY_KEY
    FROM [F_ACCESSION_DAILY] 
    where RECEIVED_MLIS_INFORMATION=1
    GROUP BY patient_id,ACCESSION_DAILY_KEY
```

This query will give me the `primary key` **accession_daily_key** of the row which contains the doctor to which the patient is associated with.

Can you please guide me on how I can get the number of patients every month that are NEW for each doctor in that specific month?

---

Edit by jcolebrand:

```
CREATE TABLE F_ACCESSION_DAILY (
    doctor VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
  , received_date DATETIME NOT NULL
  , patient_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
  , accession_daily_key INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO F_ACCESSION_DAILY (doctor,received_date,patient_id,accession_daily_key) VALUES ('A','1/1/2011','ABC123','1')
INSERT INTO F_ACCESSION_DAILY (doctor,received_date,patient_id,accession_daily_key) VALUES ('A','1/20/2011','AAA123','2')
INSERT INTO F_ACCESSION_DAILY (doctor,received_date,patient_id,accession_daily_key) VALUES ('A','1/21/2011','AAA123','3')
INSERT INTO F_ACCESSION_DAILY (doctor,received_date,patient_id,accession_daily_key) VALUES ('A','2/1/2011','ABC123','5')
INSERT INTO F_ACCESSION_DAILY (doctor,received_date,patient_id,accession_daily_key) VALUES ('A','2/9/2011','BBBYYY','6')
INSERT INTO F_ACCESSION_DAILY (doctor,received_date,patient_id,accession_daily_key) VALUES ('B','1/2/2011','ABC123','8')
INSERT INTO F_ACCESSION_DAILY (doctor,received_date,patient_id,accession_daily_key) VALUES ('B','1/20/2011','AXA435','9')
INSERT INTO F_ACCESSION_DAILY (doctor,received_date,patient_id,accession_daily_key) VALUES ('B','1/19/2011','AAA123','10')
INSERT INTO F_ACCESSION_DAILY (doctor,received_date,patient_id,accession_daily_key) VALUES ('B','2/1/2011','ABC123','12')
INSERT INTO F_ACCESSION_DAILY (doctor,received_date,patient_id,accession_daily_key) VALUES ('B','2/10/2011','BBBYYY','13')
```

Comment: How are you storing data about the patients? How do you know when they first came to the clinic?

Comment: @jcolebrand thanks so much for your question. the first time they came would be min(received_date)

Comment: Wow, that's a horrible data structure. The best you can do is to use that min date as the key for each patient.

Comment: im sorry i changed this line in the question the doctor to which the patient is associated is the LAST doctor that saw him

Comment: with the number of questions that you ask, can you please start to create [SQL Fiddles](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the table structure and data, it would be very helpful and probably faster.

Comment: @jcolebrand also the primary key is accession_daily_key

Comment: @bluefeet thank you very much for the suggestion. i will definitely do that for future q's

Comment: beyond "make it work" ... if real, actual lives are at stake here, then don't you think you should find a better model?

Comment: @swasheck feel free to add an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Note that this is on his first iteration of information, and because Zeb has already done a great job with a further answer, I'm leaving this for historical tracing reasons. Feel free to ignore this answer in favor of his, but for the iterative process, this is a good learning example.

This seems like it should do what you need, I think

```
SELECT
       MIN(received_date) AS FirstVisit
     , patient_id         AS PatientID
INTO #LookupTable
FROM F_ACCESSION_DAILY

SELECT 
       f.doctor           AS Doctor
     , COUNT(f.*)         AS CountNewPatients
     , MONTH(firstvisit)  AS Month
     , YEAR(firstvisit)   AS Year
FROM F_ACCESSION_DAILY f 
INNER JOIN #LookupTable l ON f.received_date = l.FirstVisit 
                         AND f.patient_id = l.PatientID
GROUP BY f.doctor
       , MONTH(firstvisit)
       , YEAR(firstvisit)

DROP TABLE #LookupTable
```

Comment: Notice that what I submitted and what Zebediah submitted are virtually the same.

Comment: Yes, and now we both need to update our answers to reflect the somewhat changed requirement: "if docA saw a patient in jan and docB say the same patient in october, the patient is associated with docB and we ignore any previous doctors associated with him – Артём Царионов"

Comment: @jcolebrand THANK YOU SO MUCH. can you please tell me what you've updated ? i dont see that you've updated anything in your answer? thank you

Comment: i think your answer is correct. the only change is MIN to MAX

Comment: If it works for you, however the other answer seemed to provide the dataset you asked for ...

Answer (score 4):

<s>You're probably going to have to do this in two steps with a subquery:</s>

1. get a list of all new-patient visits:

   SELECT doctor, MIN(date) AS firstvisit ,patient FROM visits GROUP BY patient;
2. Sum them up grouped by month

   SELECT doctor, COUNT(*), MONTH(firstvisit) AS month, YEAR(firstvisit) AS year FROM (...) GROUP BY doctor, MONTH(firstvisit), YEAR(firstvisit);

Putting it all together, the following should work:

```
SELECT doctor, COUNT(*) newPatients, MONTH(firstvisit) AS month, YEAR(firstvisit) AS year FROM 
        (SELECT doctor, MIN(date) AS firstvisit ,patient FROM visits GROUP BY patient)
    GROUP BY doctor, MONTH(firstvisit), YEAR(firstvisit);
```

It might be possible to do this without the subquery, but I'm not as sure that that will work properly.

OK, EDITED UPDATE:

You now need four(?) steps:

1. Determine each patient's last visit

   SELECT patient, MAX(date) lastvisit FROM visits GROUP BY patient;
2. Determine each patent's associated doctor, as the doctor who administered their last visit:

   SELECT doctor, patient FROM visits v LEFT JOIN (...) lv ON v.patient=lv.patient WHERE v.date=lv.lastvisit;
3. Determine the first visit with their latest doctor

   SELECT doctor, patient, MIN(date) firstvisit
       FROM visits v 
       LEFT JOIN (...) dp ON v.doctor=dp.doctor
       WHERE v.patient=dp.patient
       GROUP BY patient;
4. Sum each doctor's first visits per month as before:

   SELECT doctor, COUNT(*), MONTH(firstvisit) AS month, YEAR(firstvisit) AS year 
       FROM (...) GROUP BY doctor, MONTH(firstvisit), YEAR(firstvisit);

Giving a slightly terrifying and questionably efficient total:

```
SELECT doctor, COUNT(*), MONTH(firstvisit) AS month, YEAR(firstvisit) AS year 
    FROM (
    SELECT doctor, patient, MIN(date) firstvisit
        FROM visits v 
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT doctor, patient FROM visits v 
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT patient, date lastvisit 
                        FROM visits GROUP BY patient) lv 
                ON v.patient=lv.patient 
                WHERE v.date=lv.lastvisit) dp 
        ON v.doctor=dp.doctor
        WHERE v.patient=dp.patient
        GROUP BY patient) 
    GROUP BY doctor, MONTH(firstvisit), YEAR(firstvisit);
```

Again I think that this could probably be compressed down a bit at least.

EDIT2: Thanks to jcolebrand, working SQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41beb/25

```
SELECT
       t.doctor
     , COUNT(t.doctor)
     , MONTH(t.firstvisit) AS MONTH
     , YEAR(t.firstvisit) AS YEAR
  FROM (
    SELECT
           v.doctor
         , v.patient_id
         , MIN(received_date) firstvisit
      FROM F_ACCESSION_DAILY v
 LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
                   v.doctor
                 , v.patient_id
              FROM F_ACCESSION_DAILY v
         LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT patient_id
                         , received_date lastvisit
                      FROM F_ACCESSION_DAILY
                  GROUP BY patient_id
                         , received_date
                  ) lv ON v.patient_id=lv.patient_id
             WHERE v.received_date=lv.lastvisit
          ) dp ON v.doctor = dp.doctor
    WHERE v.patient_id=dp.patient_id
    GROUP BY v.patient_id
           , v.doctor
  ) t
 GROUP BY
       t.doctor
     , MONTH(t.firstvisit)
     , YEAR(t.firstvisit);
```

Comment: im sorry i changed this line in the question :: the doctor to which the patient is associated is the LAST doctor that saw him

Comment: OK, if it's the LAST doctor, then we make that a MAX function.. but if DocA saw a patient in January, then DocB saw the same patient in October.. is the october visit a new one for DocB?

Comment: great question!! a patient can only be associated with one doctor and it's going to be the doctor that LAST visited him

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't tell me if a switch counts as a new visit for DocB, nor does it tell me if this now invalidates the old new-visit to DocA.

Comment: if docA saw a patient in jan and docB say the same patient in october, the patient is associated with docB and we ignore any previous doctors associated with him

Comment: Well done--I'd not finished debugging mine to work; it was getting stuck on ABC123 visiting both docs on the same day.

Comment: @zebediah49 wouldnt we need LastVisit not FirstVisit since we want to associate a patient wtih the last doctor they saw?

Comment: You will notice we use lastVisit to find out which doctor, then use that information to find out their first visit with that doctor.

Comment: @zebediah49 can you please tell me why do we need to know the first visit with that doctor?

Comment: Because you said you wanted to know "Can you please guide me on how I can get the number of patients every month that are NEW for each doctor in that specific month?"

Comment: It is what you asked for! Also, thank @bluefeet for the first sqlfiddle